# How can I use a function delegate with an optional parameter

Tags: c#

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
Task<CurrencyResponse> credit(string id, string correlationVector = null);
```

I have a method that takes in this credit function as a function delegate:

```
protected async Task PerformWalletOperation(Func<string, string, Task<CurrencyResponse>> credit)
{
    currencyResponse = await credit(id);
}
```

However, since my last parameter (correclationVector) is an optional argument, I get a compile error and have to pass in a value. Is there a way around this without me having to call my credit like this:

```
credit(id, null);
```

Comment: What about creating another method `Task<CurrencyResponse> credit(string id)` that just calls that method using `credit(id, null)`?

Comment: I'd rather not since that credit interface is coming from an external library that I'm calling and I don't want to update that lib

Comment: You could use `Func<string, Task<CurrencyResponse>>` and pass `x => credit(x)`

Comment: @juharr I'm not sure I understand how to pass in a lambda when invoking the method. Can you add an answer with your description of how to do that?